# Angular2 Variable 'Undefined' Outside Method

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, observable

I am subscribing to an observable within a method and need to unsubscribe from it within another. The subCounter() method is called from an init function and the contents work just fine.

```
subCounter() {
  this.fml = this.playerService.counter(this.song).subscribe(data => {
    this.pos = data;
    this.time.position = Math.round(this.pos);
    this.time.dur = this.song.duration - this.time.position;
    this.time.durMinutes = Math.floor(this.time.dur / 60);
    this.time.durSeconds = ('0' + Math.ceil(this.time.dur - this.time.durMinutes * 60)).slice(-2);
    this.time.posMinutes = Math.floor(this.time.position / 60);
    this.time.posSeconds = ('0' + Math.ceil(this.time.position - this.time.posMinutes * 60)).slice(-2);
    this.time.percent = this.time.position / this.song.duration * 100;
  })
  // This works just fine
  console.log(this.fml);
}
```

When I call my touchActivate() function, it contains an unsubscribe function to that variable stored, however it throws an error as `this.fml.unsubscribe` is undefined. Console logging `this.fml` returns in an undefined object.

```
touchActivate() {
  console.log(this.fml);
  this.fml.unsubscribe();
}
```

At the top of my class I have the variable defined:
`public fml: any;`

Comment: How do you call `touchActivate` method?

Comment: @yurzui with an event listener for the `touchstart` event.

Comment: Could you show us the code for `touchstart` event listener?

Comment: @yurzui `$('.range-slider').on("touchstart", this.touchActivate);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.range-slider').on("touchstart", this.touchActivate.bind(this));
```

Or use arrow function to retain `this`:

```
$('.range-slider').on("touchstart", () => this.touchActivate());
```

Comment: The arrow function worked perfectly for me. Thank you!